# Rebuild a url with the query parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url:

```
http://www.example.com/gclid/YH67/utm/2908321/id/test
```

I would like to have the url with query parameters:

```
http://www.example.com/?gclid=YH67&utm=2908321&id=test
```

What I know is the main url `http://www.example.com/`

I would like to make the url to have the right parameter (I don't know the specific parameters of key/value).

Here is a simple example that I saw it works

```
if (window.location.href === "http://www.example.com") { 
   url = "http://www.example.com?gclid=test"; 
   window.history.pushState("", "", url); 
}
```

Comment: So you want to break the URL apart so that each key/value pair as shown in the original string as `key/value` would be a query param such as `?key=value`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Alex Yes that's it. I tried to split the url using the / and join the parts but I didn't find a way to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one -

```
function makeURL(url)
{
  var mainUrl = "http://www.example.com/";

  var urlArr = url.split(mainUrl);
  if(urlArr[1] && urlArr[1] !== "")
  {
       // assuming url will always be a perfect url
       var queryPoints = urlArr[1].split("/");
       var queryStr = "?";
       for(var i = 0; i < queryPoints.length; i+=2)
       {
          var key = queryPoints[i];
          var value = queryPoints[i+1];
          if(i+2 == queryPoints.length)
            queryStr += key+ "=" + value;
          else
            queryStr += key+ "=" + value + "&";
       }
    var queriedUrl = mainUrl + queryStr;
    console.log(queriedUrl);
    return queriedUrl;
  }
  return url;
}
```

Invoke above function like this - `makeURL("http://www.example.com/gclid/YH67/utm/2908321/id/test")`. It will return you the data in query string format.

Comment: Thank you. Nice but I don't know the positions exactly. And for example if I have one query param or nothing in url I take back http://www.example.com/?=undefined&

Comment: When I say positions I mean the number of key/values param

Comment: Updated the code to check for edge conditions.   thats fine. This snippet only assumes that the first one will be key and second one will be value. i.e. `/key/value/key2/value2/key3/value3...` and so on.

Comment: this is number independent. You can have any number of key value pairs in the url. this should work.

Comment: I think now it is not working. If I try to test it it gives me url with /

Comment: what url you are sending ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update that transform a given url to a url with query string:

```js
var url='http://www.example.com/gclid/YH67/utm/2908321/id/test';
var domain='http://www.example.com/';

function extractParams(url,domain) {
    var params=url.replace(domain,'').split('/');
    var newparams={};
    for (var i=0;i<params.length;i=i+2) {
        newparams[params[i]]=params[i+1];
    }
    
    return newparams;
}

function httpBuildQuery(params) {
 var query=[];
    for (var key in params) {
      query.push(key+'='+params[key]);   
    }
    
    return query.join('&');
}

console.log(httpBuildQuery(extractParams(url,domain)));
```